# Create duplicate values with automatic repeat values dragdown option in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to create duplicate values from a different sheet.

like:

```
ItemNr  ,    translated field  
=sheet1!C2 , ItemName  
=sheet1!C2 , Property  
=sheet1!C3 , ItemName  
=sheet1!C3 , Property  
=sheet1!C4 , ItemName  
=sheet1!C4 , Property
```

The bold marked forumula is the formula I entered in each cell manually, 
which selects the cell from the other sheet twice
However I want to use the Automatically repeat values (dragdown) function, so that I can extend these forumulas all the way to the bottom of the sheet (so basically for each Item Nr)

However once i do this instead of going on like this:

```
=sheet1!C5 , ItemName  
=sheet1!C5 , Property
```

It continues by skipping some values:

```
=sheet1!C8 , ItemName  
=sheet1!C8 , Property  
=sheet1!C9 , ItemName  
=sheet1!C9 , Property  
=sheet1!C10 , ItemName  
=sheet1!C10 , Property  
=sheet1!C14 , ItemName  
=sheet1!C14 , Property  
=sheet1!C15 , ItemName  
=sheet1!C15 , Property
```

I can solve this issue using dirty tricks like duplicating the values in sheet 1, then order by and then select from the double values.
Or by first copying it to another row and select from there.
There are probably alot more of these "Dirty" tricks, which I normally would be fine with to have a quick solution.
However in this case I have 40 more huge excel sheets that need to undergo the same kind of formula, so this time I thought of doing it correctly.
I've been searching google for about an hour and a half just to find a solution but, unfortunately I haven't found one yet.

Hopefully you got a general idea of what I'm trying to do.
And my appologies for the lack of knowledge...

Kind regards,

Chester van Ree

Comment: `been searching google for about an hour and a half` please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,2+((ROW(1:1)-1)/2))
```

As it is dragged down the cell it references will only change every two rows.

Comment: @findwindow the judge is still out on whether my crystal ball is working today or not.  Let's wait and see what the OP has to say.

Comment: Wait, god is having doubts?? Pffft

Comment: @ChestervanRee  Remember if this works for you after about 17 minutes from the time you asked the question you can mark it as correct.  You do this by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Perfect! it works exaclty as I intended :) 

Thank you!

Comment: @ChestervanRee glad to here it, remember to come back in a few minutes and mark it as correct.

Comment: needs 1 more minute :P

Comment: So what's the lottery numbers for tonight?